# what to do to not to accept decimal in input boxes

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

I used return false and many other things but nothing works. I also tried preventDefualt and stoppropogation but it is also not working. Below is my code:--

```
$('.mrEdit').keyup(function(objEvent) {
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 190)
        {
            alert(1);
            //objEvent.preventDefault();
            //objEvent.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        };
```

Comment: You can use regex to replace the unexpected entered value .

Answer (score 1):

Replacing non-numeric characters manually seems to work.

```
$('.mrEdit').keyup(function () {
    var newval = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (this.value != newval) {
       this.value = newval;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vijay - This is working perfectly fine. you save my day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it is working can you please upvote and accept this answer? It might help others.